# How to route api controllers with different areas and same names?

Tags: c#, api, model-view-controller

In my mvc app I have three different controllers:

- `JobsAdminController` which should be available at `/api/admin/jobs` and has attr `[RoutePrefix("admin/jobs")]`
- `JobsController` which should be available at `/api/jobs`
- `JobsStatusController` which should be available at `/api/jobs/status` and has attr `[RoutePrefix("jobs/status")]`

But if I trying to access `/api/admin/jobs` I enter `JobsController` insteed of `JobsAdminController`. Is it can be fixed with correct RoutePrefixes or I have to change routes using `HttpConfiguration`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to redirect, request of `/api/admin/jobs/Jobs` that not exists, to `/api/admin/jobs/JobsAdmin`?

Comment: @RezaAghaei,  no I need  GET POST DELETE requests to `/api/admin/jobs`  to be processed by `JobsAdminController` and GET POST DELETE requests to `/api/jobs`  be procesed with `JobsController`

Comment: so simply write 2 routes for those 2 urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put such route definitions before your default route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "JobsAdminRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/admin/jobs/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "JobsAdmin", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "JobsRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/jobs/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Jobs", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

This way:

- `JobsAdminController` will handle `api/admin/jobs` requests
- `JobsController` will handle `api/jobs` requests

Remember:

- Add those routes before default route, since routes will match in order they registered and if the default route is registered first, `api/admin/jobs` will match with a admin controller with jobs as id parameter that will not found.